# Is there a way to convert a VARCHAR to a DATE in AWS Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Attempting to convert a variable character data type field that is time related (eg `'2015-Q1'`) to a timestamp (or time) data type field in order to compare with a different field.

Need to be able to use `dateadd()` on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TO_DATE` function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html

Along with `TO_TIMESTAMP`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html

example:

`select to_timestamp(to_date('2015-Q1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'HH24:MI:SS')`;